# Vagrant Windows: Unable to mount one of your Folders

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to install a Homestead on my Win 10 PC and I am currently stuck at this error:

[image: Screenshot of Output]

My Homestead.yaml confing is this:

```
folders:
  - map: C:\Projects\Website\Code
   to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and fix that

if you use .homestaed foder in your user folder and cloned homestead github to other folder got to that folder and edit that. not from .homestead folder.